# Select column values in table comma seperated using comma seperated values in condition

Tags: mysqli

I have list of value like 2,3,4(comma separated) and a table which has ids like 1,2,3,4,5,6 call it as table1. From table1 table i have emp_name.
Here what i want is to get list of employees in comma separated values based on list give in the condition.

To achieve this i tried group concate, and find_in set but unable to get desired out put.
eg. select emp_name from emp_table where emp_id in('2,3,4', '1,2,3,4,5,6');
desired output. mr2,mr3,mr4

I know i can achieve it by looping through it, but i want mysql way.

Any help would be appreciable.
Thanyou

Answer (score 0):

Having a table like

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

you may query it like this

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS employee FROM employees WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

and the result would be

```
Sandeep,Mohammed,Sabri,Ashtam,Tamal
```

Comment: this isn't exact thing i am looking for.

Comment: Could you try to better explain what you actually need ? I hope you are not storing multiple comma separated values in a single cell, are you ?

Comment: You must not, otherwise you will have a very hard time trying to filter on them. Every table cell must contain either NULL or a single value. If you need more values - then store them in multiple rows.